# Getting IODeviceTree path using IOKit

Tags: c, iokit, macos

I'm trying to get the IODeviceTree path of a device using the IOKit framework. I'm able to get the IOService path (`IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@B/AppleMCP79AHCI`) of the device using this code:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDict = NULL;
matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("AppleMCP79AHCI");
io_service_t sataService;
io_string_t path;
sataService = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict);
IORegistryEntryGetPath(sataService, kIOServicePlane, path);
NSLog(@"%s", path);
```

However, I need to get the path for the device in the `IODeviceTree` plane. In the `IODeviceTree` plane, the path would be something like `IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/SATA@B`. I tried simply replacing `kIOServicePlane` with `kIODeviceTreePlane` but it returned nothing. I have no experience with `IOKit`, so I'm pretty sure theres something obvious I'm doing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was just using a class name that didn't exist in the IODeviceTree.